# passing string to onclick() in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to pass a string to onclick function along with "this" of form element.

```
    var title ="excerpt";
    var button = '<input onclick="thirdStage(this.form,"+title+");" type="button" value="final stage">';
```

Could you tell me what is wrong here ?

Thanks

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `' + title + '`

Comment: do you developer console on your browser .. you can try yourself many things there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It it really not recommended writing functions directly into tags, or storing tags as raw strings.  Almost all serious development depends on a general javascript library such as jQuery.  To accomplish this in jQuery,

```
var title = "dddd";
var btn = jQuery('<input type="button" value="final stage">').click(
               function(e) { 
                  thirdStage(this.form, title)
               });
```

Be warned that I did not worry about testing the above.  The this.form I think is not quite right.  The point using something like jQuery is critical.  Seriously.

Answer (score 1):

your variable `title` is not appending in variable `button` properly

try this

```
var title ="excerpt";
var button = '<input onclick="thirdStage(this.form,\"'+title+'\");" type="button" value="final stage">';
```

Comment: try this value looks like a variable if dont't use \"

Comment: This works, but shouldn't we be guiding people to leverage industry standard practices?  Or at least point them out?

Comment: yes you are right but i faced that problem in my initial works. so i put it at right way

Answer (score -1):

You are using the same quotes outside and inside. Change it like so:

```
var title ="excerpt";
var button = '<input onclick="thirdStage(this.form,\''+title+'\');" type="button" value="final stage">';
```

Comment: -1: `title` is not a string, it is a variable. check the first line.

Comment: even its not right? this will use expert as a variable not value

Comment: your code still has a problem, you have to wrap it in another quotation,to make it a real string.